# How to automatically update a blog post after X amount of time has passed? Node.js Express Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to update the priority of a blog post if its older than say 2-3 days and i am not sure how to achieve this. In my route i try to identify if the blog post is older than 2 days, and if that was the case, it would change the priority from 'high' to ''. So far no luck and from what i read online, it seems that there may be npm packages that can achieve this for me.

> Mongoose Schema

```
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  image: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  priority: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
    trim: true
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  author: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      trim: true
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  viewCount: {
    type: Array,
    timestamps: {
      createdAt: 'createdAt',
      updatedAt: 'updatedAt',
      trim: true
  } 
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  categorySlug: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  tags: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  updated: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now , trim: true},
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Comment',
      trim: true
    },
  ],
},{
  timestamps: {
      createdAt: 'createdAt',
      updatedAt: 'updatedAt'
    }
 });
```

> My Route

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {

blog.find({ priority: ['high'] })
.sort({date: -1})
.limit(1)
.exec(function(err, high) {
  if (err || !high) {
    console.log(err);
    req.flash('Troubleshooting Error')
    redirect('/');
  } else {
    if(high && Date.now() > high.createdAt + 86400000  ) {
      var priority = {slug: 'slug', priority: 'high'}
      var newPriority = '';
      blog.findOneAndUpdate(priority, newPriority,function(err, updated){
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Successfully updated priority');
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is in your `findOneAndUpdate`? i.e. Have you verified that `high` is what you think it is, right before the if statement?

Comment: No i am not sure that is the issue.

Comment: You should probably `console.log(high)` right inside your `exec` function, because right now it looks like blog posts are being returned since you're doing `blog.find` but you're treating the results as priorities.